# How to start previous activity from listview onItemClick?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I have ActivityA which has a button and a listview, and I have ActivityB which has a set of properties that you can manipulate. When you set these properties and click save it will add an item to the listview in ActivityA.

I would like to click on the listview item and have it populate ActivityB with the changes that were previously made.

Would I have to feed the start activity these changes and save the changes in a database to read from? Or is there a easier way.

Comment: This is a classic use case for `startActivityForResult`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start Activity B from A  as startActivityForResult() and on manage the result of B on Activity A, Look this [How to manage `startActivityForResult` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/android-how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result).
If they are like settings or some data you want to preserve you need to saved on in a Database, shared preferences: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html
keep in mind  that  is not recommended to use shared preferences, to save a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Are you attempting to just send data between the two activities?
If so, this can be achieved by placing the data needed in to a bundle in say ActivityA and adding it to the intent and calling ActivityB and retrieving it in the onCreate(), or visa versa.

However, if you would like to realtime update the listview from say ActivityB you will need to look in to using Fragments.

[Developer Android: Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)